# Кракозябры при чтении txt файла

Tags: php, файлы

Файл в кодировке utf-8 без bom. В файле русский текст, нужно считать и записать в бд, для теста решил вывести содержимое

```
$f = file_get_contents('ti.txt');
echo $f;
```

Выдаёт �����

```
$f = file_get_contents('ti.txt');
$f = mb_convert_encoding($f, 'UTF-8');
echo $f;
```

Выдаёт ïîðíî ÿïîíêè â óíèôîðì

```
$f = file_get_contents('ti.txt');
$f = iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8",$f);
echo $f;
```

Выдаёт ïîðíî ÿïîíêè â óíèôîðì

Comment: а сам файл скрипта в какой кодировке?

Comment: @Jean-Claude UTF-8

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @splash58 смысл?

Comment: предполагаю, что браузер по умолчанию показывает не utf-8

Comment: Так же мучился этой бедой. Все перерыли и перекопали, пока ментор не спросил через что создал текстовый файл. Через блокнот не создавать текстовый файл, там старая кодировка вроде как. Попробуйте создать файл через vscode или другую IDE и сохранить в формате .txt и все получится (предварительно сменив кодировку сохраняемых файлов на utf-8 without bom).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$t = file_get_contents('ti.txt');
$get  = mb_detect_encoding($t, array('utf-8', 'cp1251'));
echo iconv($get,'UTF-8',$t);
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте указать кодировку через *header*

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $f = file_get_contents('ti.txt');
    echo $f;
?>
```

Comment: тоже не помогало

Comment: @Rufex ну главное что ответ найден =)

Answer (score 1):

С кодировками, php и БД не всегда все просто. Сюда еще прибавляются проблемы с разными версиями. Даже если для базы указана определенная кодировка, сами данные могут быть совсем другой. При работе клиента (скрипта) с БД можно указать в какой кодировке получать (принимать) данные. Например, в БД хранится UTF-8, клиент просит выдать в cp1251, никаких проблем нет, все работает. А если попросить в cp1252, то вместо кириллицы будут "кракозябры", потому что её нет в этой кодировке. Очень понятная [статья](http://phpfaq.ru/mysql/charset).

Answer (score -1):

Это не UTF-8, а CP1251 или CP1252. Попробуйте и отпишитесь =)

```
$f = file_get_contents('ti.txt');
$f = mb_convert_encoding($f, 'cp1251');
echo $f;
```